# local variable 'mes' referenced before assignment in python?

Tags: python, variables, pycharm

I'm working on this function that converts a Julian day to a gregorian date, the output should look like ex. `22.0,12.0,2000` thats why in print I have those three variables, but when I run it, it gives me the error:

> local variable 'mes' referenced before assignment.

Also, "A" appears to be highlighted in yellow with the warning "local variable A might be referenced before assignment". I don't know how to fix it.

I've tried changing the indentation, but I don't see what's wrong.

Below is my function:

```
def JD2fechaGregoriana(fecha):
   fecha1=int(fecha+0.5)
   fecha2=float(fecha1-fecha)
   Z =fecha1
   F = fecha2
   if (Z<2299161):
       A=Z
   elif (Z>= 2291161):
       alpha=int((Z-1867216.25)/36524.25)
       A= Z + 1 + alpha -int(alpha/4)

   B= A +1524
   C= int((B-122.1)/365.25)
   D= int(365.25*C)
   E= int((B-D)/30.6001)
   dia1= B-D - int(30.6001*E)+F

   if (E>14):
      mes=E-1
   elif (E==14 or E==15):
      mes=E-13
   if (mes>2):
      anio=C-4716
   elif(mes==1 or mes==2):
      anio=C-4715

   print(dia1,mes,anio)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using variable `mes` in an `if...else` and then printing its value.
Even though variable `mes` exists, you are assigning its value inside `if...else` block, naturally this will create variable inside the `if` block, and therefore when you try to print `mes` it gives the error:

You should first declare variable as `0` before if statement, and then further use this in if block.

eg:

```
.....
mes=0
if (E>14):
  mes=E-1
......
```

And same goes with variable `A`.

It would work!

Answer (score 0):

Friend, review the topic of the scope of the variables, declare the variables before comparing them in IF -ELSE. Initialize them with some value. For example

`month = 0`

```
A = 0
```